# Incoming cellular calls ring on all my iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi, ios, call

When I receive an incoming cellular call on my iPhone 5 (iOS 8.3), it is propagated to all my other devices (including a wifi only iPad) connected to the same wifi network.

I guess that's an activated by default functionality, can it be deactivated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable on specific iDevices, go to Settings > FaceTime > iPhone Cellular Calls & switch off.

On a Mac, launch Facetime, then Preferences > iPhone Cellular Calls - uncheck.

Comment: So does it mean I can only stop the call propagation from the "slave" devices ?

Is there a way to stop it directly from the device that received the cellular call ?

Comment: No. Each device is equally capable of receiving or not receiving the call, so each must be disabled individually. There is no 'master switch'.

Comment: it's a bit annoying. A cellular number is strongly linked to an iPhone and is a private thing. So why another user sharing the same iTunes account can decide without your consent to also receive your phone calls on his own device ?

Comment: Golden rule - one user per account. End of problem. Accounts were never designed to be used by more than one person. If you want to share information/apps/music etc, use Family Sharing.

Comment: Yes :-), family sharing just arrives on the market. Previously (iOS < 8) there was no other simple way to share contents with your family.