# Best practices to migrate from a single shared iTunes account to family sharing

Tags: ios, itunes, migration, accounts, family-sharing

Since iOS 4, my family is equiped with multiple iOS devices. I used the same iTunes account on all devices to share :

- Applications
- Photos
- Notes
- Musics
- Data (game progression)

With iOS 8 Apple introduced family sharing. Firstly I didn't see any advantage in this new functionality. 
But with this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/189093/95862), I understand that 1 account per physical person is the new golden rule.

So what are the best practices to migrate from a single shared iTunes account to family sharing without loosing anything ?

Some data (game progression) aren't shared accross all devices, how can I be sure that my daughter will not loose her data when she will use her newest iTunes account ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would create subsequent accounts for other family members, then you can use your current account as the "parent" or "leader" account and then add the new accounts to the family.

You are still using your original account so you're guaranteed not to loose anything, the others should also have access to the content you choose to share with other family members.

Comment: But, when I will setup my daughter device with her new account, will she loose every data created before with my account or the family sharing also cares about the data ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how game data works. She may loose that data after she uses a new account. Unless the data is saved locally on the device and not on iCloud. It would be different for each app.